# PHP - Delete last 2 characters in a loop

Tags: php

I have the following which produces results for me.

```
foreach($authArray as $key=>$value){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$value' LIMIT 1");
    $author = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $author['fullname'] .', ';
}
```

It prints it out perfect, except on the last run it still adds the comma and space, is there a way i can strip this from the last result, so its:

```
name, name, name, name
```

Instead of the following

```
name, name, name, name,
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

A better way of doing this would be to separate out the handling of database results from the view/output logic, and then you can sidestep the issue all together, using `implode` to allow PHP to join each of your authors together into a single string, split by your delimiter of a comma and a space:

```
// your loop {
  $authors[] = $author['fullname'];
}

// your output
echo implode(', ', $authors);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concate the data into a string and then remove the last 2 chars using

`$author['fullname'] = substr($author['fullname'], 0, -2);`

Refer the manual for `substr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing each author out you could put them in a string and then simply use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to take off the trailing comma and finally echo the whole string.

Comment: You're asking a question as an answer to a question. Either you should have asked your question in a comment on the original question, or you should have written your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

this will probably work

```
foreach($authArray as $key=>$value){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$value' LIMIT 1");
    $author = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    //echo $author['fullname'] .', ';
}

$name_count = count($author[]);

for($x=0;$x<$name_count ;$x++){
    if($x == $name_count -1){
        echo $author['fullname'];
    }else{
        echo $author['fullname'].", ";
    }
}
```

the idea is to detect the last array index, so that we can apply all the commas after each name except to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

don't ever echo inside foreach

```
$var = '';
foreach($authArray as $key=>$value){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$value' LIMIT 1");
    $author = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $var .= $author['fullname'] .', ';
}

echo trim($var,', ');
```